# Dangers of deleting C:\$Extend\$UsnJrnl:$J:$DATA

Tags: windows-vista, partitioning, ntfs, journaling

Got a Vista laptop with Wubi Ubuntu installed (read: Ubuntu on virtual disks located on the NTFS partition). I only use Ubuntu, but the disk performance is so poor that I want to switch to a normal partition install.

**The problem is that the disk was quite full in it's time (~8 GB were free from 130GB), so the USN journal is scattered all over the disk, and since it's unmovable, making the disk partition impossible.**

The only thing I can do is to **delete it**. I looked at a number of sites, Microsoft's Technet counted, but I still don't really understand the risks of the deleting the journal.

**What am I risking? Would you recommend doing it?**

Comment: Note that the NTFS journal and the USN journal aren't the same thing. The former is used by the file system itself for reliability; the latter is used by userspace programs for change monitoring.

Answer (score 10):

The USN journal's purpose is to provide a complete list of filesystem changes to various userspace programs like virus scanners or file indexers (e.g. "Everything").

You can safely delete this journal, using `fsutil` on Windows, or `rm` on Linux (ntfs-3g):

```
fsutil usn deletejournal C:
```

It's a good idea to recreate it later though:

```
fsutil usn createjournal m=0 a=0 C:
```

Do not confuse the change/USN journal with the one used by NTFS itself, which is kept in `$LogFile`. The NTFS journal (log) is a required component, used to prevent filesystem corruption.

Comment: Thanks. I already feel a bit more confident (I'll still do a complete disk backup though, just to be sure).

Question though: won't the journal recreate itself automatically?

Comment: It works well! On Windows 11, the command is like so: fsutil usn deletejournal /D C:

Answer (score 2):

The correct command line to delete the USN journal is:
fsutil usn deletejournal /D C:

Comment: Add a little more detail and explain why this is different than the other answer and why this should be an answer rather than a comment to ask the person that answered to fix something like perhaps a simple oversight on a switch or parameter of the command.