# Shrinking Volume in Windows Disk Management not shrinking

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, windows-11, dualboot

This has been asked in the past, and been answered, but none of those solutions have worked, which is why I'm creating a post.

Quick Background on my system:

- I have two drives.
- The drive that I'm talking about is an HDD Drive with a capacity of 931.51 GB. The current free space at the time of writing is exactly 220.59 GB.
- I need to shrink the drive by 100 GB to make space for a dual boot that I'm doing.
- My computer is currently running Windows 11

So, I'm attempting to install Linux along with my Windows system, but when shrinking my second drive's partition, it only gives me (roughly) 25 GB of available shrink space, when in reality my free space is over 220 GB. The error that is shown is, "You can not shrink a volume beyond the point where any unmovable files are located." and it shows that I can shrink about to roughly 25 GB.

I've read articles and posts on this issue and I'm seeing that I have to disable system restore, the page file, and hibernation. After doing all three, I've restarted my computer to no change. Is there anything I'm missing or something else?

Comment: There's no guarantee the files that can't be moved are the page file etc.. You'd need to use a defragger and see what files can not be moved and/or try moving them using the defragger. You need a defrag / optimize tool that gives you more control than the built-in windows defrag tool.

Comment: Have you determined what the unmovable system file is exactly? There are lots of questions with detailed answers that go into detail on how to shrink your system partition

Comment: Thank You! That does help. A question though, for me, the file is showing as: "\$Extend\$UsnJrnl:$J:$DATA" and I'm unable to figure out what that is. Do you have any idea, what it may be?

Comment: I did a bit more digging. Turns out that is just the USn Journal and can quickly be cleaned up as shown here. https://superuser.com/questions/819901/dangers-of-deleting-c-extend-usnjrnljdata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist in resizing your partition within Windows, the link [How can i shrink a windows 10 partition](https://superuser.com/questions/1017764/how-can-i-shrink-a-windows-10-partition) provided by *Ramhound* should be very useful.

But as you are going to install Linux, typically you already have a Linux Live-CD/USB. Many of them have included the tool [GParted](https://gparted.org/) as Disk Management Tool.

1. Boot into the Linux LiveCD/USB and start GParted
2. Select the disk to edit
3. Right-click on the partition to resize
4. Choose `Resize/Move`
5. Change the partition settings
6. Execute the changes by the button <kbd>Resize/Move</kbd>

[image]

If required the tool will move the data to a new position.

*Be sure to keep the "Microsoft reserved partition" untouched and just before the Windows partition.*

---

**Alternative**
If you are within the Linux installer many of them offer "manual partitioning" at the point of choosing the storage media. Choosing "manual partitioning" will call a partitioning tool. Often this is `GParted`. — But to be sure about the right tool, you should prefer the Linux live session.

---

**NOTE**
If `GParted` is missing in your Live-Linux, you can use the package manager to temporarily install `GParted` to the Live-Linux. That will only take place within the RAM, so after a reboot such an installation will be gone.

For a Debian based Linux this should do it:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gparted
```